# running a system app on at the end of boot completed

Tags: android

I have a system app running in priv app folder. I want it to boot ir after wifi conected on boot completed, so its likely to start at the very end of the bootup. How can I do it, how to control boot order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `priority` attirubte on the `IntentFilter` for your manifest registered `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="...boot received..." />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```